# Terraform modules: correct references of variables?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm writing a terraform script to create an EKS cluster with its worker nodes on AWS. First time doing it so I'm a bit confused.
Here is the folder organisation:

```
├─── Int AWS Account
│   ├─── variables.tf
│   ├─── eks-cluster.tf (refers the modules)
│   ├─── others
│
├─── Prod AWS Account
│   ├─── (will be the same than Int with different settings in variables)
│
├─── ReadMe.md
│
├─── data sources
│
├─── Modules
│   ├─── cluster.tf
│   ├─── worker-nodes.tf
│   ├─── worker-nodes-sg.tf
```

I am a bit confused regarding how to use and pass variables. Right now, what I'm doing is that I refer to ${var.name} in the module folder, in the eks-cluster.tf, I either put a direct value name = blabla (mostly avoiding it), or refer to the variable again and have a variable file in the account folder.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I get your question correctly but in general you would want to keep your module files with variables only, as modules are intended to be generic so you can easily include them in different environments.

When including the module in `eks_cluster_int.tf` or `eks_cluster_prod.tf` you would then pass the values for all variables defined in the module itself. This way you can use the environment specific values in the same module.

```
module "cluster" {
  source = "..."

  var1 = value1    # directly passing value
  var2 = ${var.int_specific_var}  # can be defined in variables.tf of environment
  ...
}
```

Does this answer your question?